# AKS - Terraform's network_profile block

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, azure-vm-scale-set

When creating an `aks` cluster using `terraform` and `azurerm` provider you can specify this block :

```hcl
  network_profile {
    network_plugin     = var.network_plugin
    network_policy     = var.network_policy
    load_balancer_sku  = "Standard"
    docker_bridge_cidr = var.docker_bridge_cidr
    service_cidr       = var.service_cidr
    dns_service_ip     = var.dns_service_ip
  }
```

I've read [this page](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster) (and many more!) a few times but I still don't quite understand what it means.

- `network_pluggin` : Kubenet vs Azure CNI; why to use one over another ? I understood that kubenet allowed having less chance of ip exhaustion than Azure CNI, byt Azure CNI is recommanded when enable `AAD pod identity` - am I right?
- `network_policy`: this one I think is the way one can manage the internal k8s's `network policies`
- `load_balancer_sku` : this one is clear to me; no problem
- `docker_bridge_cidr`: I think this isn't really used by `azure` and is more like some legacy stuff, `docker` requiring to be configured on the worker nodes.
- `service_cidr` : I have no idea what the doc means by "*The Network Range used by the Kubernetes service. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.*"
- `dns_service_ip` : as above I'm not really sure

Also, when I provide my `default_node_pool` a `vnet_subnet_id` to live in, it populates the given subnet with **31** `Scale set instance` tho I've only given my cluster a `min_count` of **1** and `max_count` of **2** and the `vnet_subnet_id` is a `/24` (`251` free IP). Where that `31` instances come from ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `network_plugin` = AAD Pod Identity will work with `Kubenet` but is not a recommended setup as of [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-azure-ad-pod-identity#update-an-existing-aks-cluster-with-azure-cni). [Kubenet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-kubenet) also uses a so called Overlay Network and is doing therefore NAT, this means AKS nodes gets IPs inside your Subnet and the Pods receive an IP address from a logically different address space. [Azure CNI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-azure-cni) assign IP addresses from your Subnet to Nodes and also to Pods. You need to think before how many Nodes & Pods you will have in your subnet to not run into the issue that no IPs are left for new Pods or Nodes. [Here](https://mehighlow.medium.com/aks-kubenet-vs-azure-cni-363298dd53bf) you can find an article that is doing a performance comparison.
- `network_policy` = yes, it is to enable Kubernetes Network Policies. If you are using Azure as Network Plugin, you can use Azure or Calico as network policy. Calico hast the benefit of [GlobalNetworkPolicies](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/reference/resources/globalnetworkpolicy).
- `docker_bridge_cidr`= it is legacy but def. needed as of today
- `service_cidr` = It is the CIDR for [Kubernetes Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) inside you Cluster.
- `dns_service_ip` = Needs to be inside the `service_cidr`. By default Kubernetes will assign x.x.x.10 as [DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) IP. You can change this here. That is why Azure CNI requires little more planning,

To answer your final question, Azure CNI reserves all IP addresses upfront, so given your Setup with 1 Node & the default setting of `max_pods=30` it will reserve 31 IPs inside your subnet.